# how do I just show content from target page

Tags: iframe

How do I load just the target html page and not the surrounding frames?

I am using this code as the link to open the page:

`<a href="/apex/page" target ="myiframe">Customer</a> <br>`

I am loading the content into a html page with these params:

`<iframe name="myiframe" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; border: none;"></iframe>`

-Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 0):

did you try `style="overflow: hidden;"`? It works for me..